# How to show multiple features selection button/dialog box on the map using .NET?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

If you use the Edit tool to click a location on the map with overlapping features, a small icon [image: button icon] Selection chip pops up with a dialog box previewing the selectable features where you clicked, so you can distinguish the correct feature from the overlapping ones.

How to get this "selection chip" from code (using .NET)? What interface I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ISelectionResolutionChip`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002000000164000000) interface:

```cs
public void GetSelectionChipByCLSID()
{
 //If your project is an Add-In you are given the Application. Otherwise you can get the app from the
  //hook parameter.
  UID editorUID = new UIDClass();
  editorUID.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";
  _Editor = ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUID) as IEditor;


  UID chipUid = new UIDClass();
  chipUid.Value = "esriEditor.SelectionResolutionChip";

  ISelectionResolutionChip _SelectionChip = editor.FindExtension(chipUid) as ISelectionResolutionChip;
}
```